# Fresh install of 64bit Ubuntu needs flash but adobe doesn't have a version for me

Tags: 64-bit, installation, ubuntu-10.04, package-management, flash-player

I need flash to watch YT videos. YT said "You need to upgrade your Adobe Flash Player to watch this video." with a [link](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) to download flash. I'm running 10.04 so I see possible choices for myself: 1) a .deb file for Ubuntu 8.04+ or APT (whats this??) for Ubuntu 9.04. I downloaded the deb file and when I opened it in the installer it said that I have the wrong architecture. Anyone have an idea about how to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found it. I have to use synaptic to install flashplugin-installer. Its works now!

Comment: Lucky you, when I used 64-bit Ubuntu on the old days of 7.04 I had to go throught all the hassle of installing 32-bit Firefox with all the plugins, after which not even half of it worked.

Comment: boo! Yeah that sucks. Well I had Ubuntu running on this machine for a while (9.04, 9.10 etc) and I had flash working then. I guess I just forgot what what I did in the first place to get it going.

Answer (score 1):

If you enable Canonical's partner repository, you'll also find the packages *adobe-flashplugin* and *adobeair* in your package manager.

To enable this extra repository:

1. Open *System > Administration > Software Sources*
2. Go to the "Other Software" tab
3. Check the box next to this line:
   `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu lucid partner`

Now you'll need to update/refresh your package manager (`sudo aptitude update` on the commandline, or the *Reload* button in Synaptic), and these packages will be available.

Comment: +1 for adobe air. I didn't know that!

Comment: I did as you said but those packages don't show up. If I click the "Origin" button in synaptic, what would the repo be named there?

Comment: @djtriplethreat: i don't use Synaptic very often, but it looks like the `lucid/main (archive.canonical.com)` entry is where you'll find those packages.  if you aren't finding them, either they aren't available for your architecture or you haven't enabled the correct repository.  i'm not using a 64-bit architecture so your package list may differ.

Comment: Ok, I think they aren't available for 64-bit architecture. Thanks for the help though. For 64-bit architecture I'll have to go with what I found because it works for my question.